# How do I participate in ITTF events as a player?

Tags: table-tennis

I looked through all the ITTF events but I couldn't find a way to register for any of these events. I am a new table tennis player and my objective is to play in official matches.

On the ITTF events webpage, it is just dates and locations, but no register button or link. Could someone explain how these events work?

Additional question: Some said that it is free to participate in ITTF events, and some said that it costs $10,000. Which is true?

Comment: Are you beating players at your club? From experience of being a member of sports clubs (but not table tennis) You need to play in club competitions, if you do well then you may be asked to represent the club in their local league and you begin to make your way up the levels of competitions.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question as asked: you (personally) can't enter those highest level tournaments; entry is by invitation only.

So, how *do* you get invited? My showing that you are good enough in the second tier of tournaments, something like national championships. However, they are probably invitation only as well.

So, how do you get invited to national championships? Probably by competing in the highest level leagues in your country and consistently winning matches. How do you get to play in those leagues? By persuading a club that you are good enough. How do you persuade a club you are good enough? By winning matches in lower level leagues. And so on, and so on until you're at beginner level leagues.

It all begins with joining a club.